# Saving custom variables in Keras .h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I'm developing a RNN for a project and I need to train it on a computer and be able to predict on another. The solution I found is to save the model into a .h5 file using the code below:

```py
... # Train the data etc....
model.save("model.h5")
```

My problem is that I need to store some meta-data from my training dataset and pre-process and be able to load it together with the model. (e.g. name of dataset file, size of the dataset file, number of characters, etc...)

I don't want to store this information in a second file (e.g. a .txt file) because I would have to use two files. I don't want to use any additional library or framework for this task.

I was thinking (*brainstorming*) a code like this:

```
model.save("model.h5", metaData={'myVariableName': myVariable})
```

And to load would be:

```
myVariable = model.load("model.h5").getMetaData('myVariableName')
```

I know this is not possible in the [current version](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) and I already read Keras doc, but I couldn't find any efficient method to do that. Notice that what I'm asking is different from [`custom_object`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#handling-custom-layers-or-other-custom-objects-in-saved-models) because want to save and load my own variables.

Is there a smarter approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know what `keras` provides, but `h5py` certainly lets you store metadata, as attributes of the file or a group (or dataset) within that file.  And if you are talking about things like names and sizes don't worry about efficiency - that's only an issue when saving/loading datasets of thousands of values.   http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html

Comment: Did you find out any more about this?